# How can I remove all the EVs from my Pokemon?

Tags: pokemon-fifth-generation

I have a level 100 Gengar that I moved to my recently-finished Black cartridge.  I never paid attention to EVs in the past gen, but now I hear EVs take effect immediately rather than on level up, so I could theoretically re-ev train him.

How would I go about resetting his EVs to 0, given that I only have access to items in the fifth gen?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Feed him **11 Pomeg** (lowering HP), **Kelpsy** (lowering Attack EV), **Qualot** (lowering Defense), **Hondew** (lowering Special Attack), **Grepa** (lowering Special Defense), and **Tamato Berries** (lowering Speed).

If a Pokémon has over 100 EVs in a stat, the EV-lowering berry will reduce it to 100 no matter how high it is, and after that, each berry will decrease the stat by 10 EVs after that. Because of this, feeding a Pokémon 11 of a stat decreasing berry will always result in 0 EVs in that stat.

#### This is assuming you can gain access to the EV berries. As far as I am aware, you can't find them in game yet. These berries are the only way you can decrease EVs.

Comment: Unfortunately you can't access the EV berries in Black and White yet. The berries are still coded in, so eventually they'll probably be available through the Dream World.

Comment: Well that sucks.

Answer (score -1):

IF you have Action Replay you can do the 999 all berries code. It's so awesome. I originally did not EV train my Jellicent, my Ferrothorn, or any of the pokemon I used to beat the game except for my Teriyaki (it's one of those legendary four legged guys. I can't spell or pronounce its name so I'll just use the lulzy nickname I gave it), but then I got Action Replay and have all the berries and just reset them and EV trained them from like level ninty-something. Since EV's are gained gradually in BW and not by leveling up it doesn't matter what level you are at which is the coolest thing ever! I was even able to EV train my original starter though I couldn't change its nature to Timid which would have been better as it was a Snivy.

Comment: This isn't a very useful answer; it's mostly a personal account with the actual answer being just "use a cheat device".